# access navigationview header from another activity

Tags: java, android

I have navigationview in MainActivity when I opened I click on menu item "Login" to open LoginActivity,
in LoginActivity I want to change navigationview header in MainActivity:

```
    public void btnClickHandler(View view) {
    if (!validate()) { }
    else {

        String url =""; // I hide my url

        StringRequest PostREQUEST = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    final JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
                    final JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(0);
                    final String status = obj.getString("sign-in");

                    if (status.equals("succeeded")) {
                        NavigationView NavBox = findViewById(R.id.NavBar); // I get error here because this is LoginActivity and navigationview is in MainActivity

                        View header = NavBox.getHeaderView(0); // NavBar header
                        TextView user_name = header.findViewById(R.id.username);
                        user_name.setText(obj.getString("name")); // Change title from Guest to Username

                        Menu menu = NavBox.getMenu(); // NavBar menu
                        MenuItem logout = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login);
                        logout.setTitle(R.string.signout); // Change title from Login to Logout

                        finish();
                    } else {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                                .setMessage(R.string.login_message)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { dialog.dismiss(); }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { error.printStackTrace(); }
        }) {
            @Override protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params; // name email password
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(PostREQUEST);
    }
}
```

but I get error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
After login I save account data to SharedPreferences
then I use this code in MainActivity after closing LoginActivity

```
@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    account = shared.getString("Account_JsonString", null); 

    View header = NavBox.getHeaderView(0);
    Menu menu = NavBox.getMenu();
    TextView user_name = header.findViewById(R.id.username);
    MenuItem logout = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login);

    if (account != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(account);
            JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(0);
            String username = obj.getString("name");
            Toast.makeText(this,this.getString(R.string.welcome_message) + " " + username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            user_name.setText(username);
            logout.setTitle(R.string.signout);
        } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    } else {
        user_name.setText(R.string.guest);
        logout.setTitle(R.string.signin);
    }
}
```

That way I can update Navigation view header and menu